# Update class data when using event listener

Tags: javascript

I'm building a simple drawing app.
Let's say I have 4 classes:

```
App.js handles the communication between the classes
Pixels.js stores the image data
Display.js displays the data
Load.js loads in data
```

Usually from within the App class, I can do something like

```
$('#icon-flip').mouseup((e) =>
{
  this.pixels.flip_pixels();
  this.display.update(this.pixels.get_pixels());
});
```

Now I've added a Load class and my problem is that I don't know how to let the App class know that the data was completely loaded and processed, as the Load class should not know about the App class.

This is the Load class

```
class Load
{

  constructor(config)
  {
    this.config = config;
    this.setup_load_input();
  }

  setup_load_input()
  {
    let element = document.createElement('div');
    element.innerHTML = '<input type="file" id="input-load" style="display: none">';
    let fileInput = element.firstChild;
    document.body.append(fileInput);
    var that = this;
    fileInput.addEventListener('change',function() {  that.read_file_data(fileInput); });
  }

  read_file_data(fileInput)
  {
    var file = fileInput.files[0];

      if (file.name.match(/\.(spm|json)$/)) 
      {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = () => 
        {
          this.parse_file(reader.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);    
      } else {
          alert("File not supported, .spm or .json files only");
      }
  }


  parse_file(file) 
  {
    this.imported_file = JSON.parse(file);
  }

  get_imported_file()
  {
    return this.imported_file;
  }

}
```

I trigger it from the App class with

```
$('#icon-load').mouseup((e) =>
{
  $("#input-load").trigger("click");
});
```

After the data got loaded and parsed, I need to

```
this.pixels.update(this.load.get_imported_file());
this.display.update(this.pixels.get_pixels());
```

But I don't know how to do this as I don't know when the Load class finished processing the data. I figured the solution might be a callback, but since I'm a noob I don't know how.

I'm sorry for the long post and bad code quality. Thanks for any helpful support!

Comment: this isn't going to solve your problem, but you should really put your opening curlies on the same line, not on a new one.

Comment: If your comment start "this isn't going to solve your problem" then perhaps its better not to leave it. +1 for Allman braces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass in an event handler to `Load`? For example:

```
/* App.js */

function updateThings() {
    this.pixels.flip_pixels();
    this.display.update(this.pixels.get_pixels());
}

// then later...
new Load({ onLoad: updateThings.bind(this) });

/* Load.js */

// In read_file_data()...
reader.onload = () => {
   this.parse_file(reader.result);
   this.config.onLoad();
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much vleong for this solution and taking the time to focus on my problem. I really appreciate it, that was very helpful!